# Is there any way to enter the value manually in drop down list?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have created a window with drop down list. So my question is I don't want to  scroll down and select the values always if i know what values. So instead of doing like this Is  there any way to enter the value manually in drop down list?
(Drop down list should be flexible for enter the values manually and select the values)

Comment: Hi, can you try to post a simplified example of the code you're using? It's a little hard to understand what is it you're trying to achieve and what approach you're using.

Comment: Really do we need share the codes for drop down list ? because using app builder i have created that window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Set your combo-box to the Drop-Down type. With or without auto-completion.

[image]

Comment: Hello Jensd Sir. Its working very well thanks for your quick support